# TIME_TO_SEC ? SEC_TO_TIME

Tags: mysql, sql

Im using mySQL

[image]

i have a calculation which return the value of totalUTinMinutes column in minutes and i want it to convert back into hours, column "T" but i got that result instead of 08:09:[some secs here].

any suggestion or solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you show your calculation? There seems to be a factor 60 missing from it.

Comment: i cant put my entire query its long

Comment: ill just edit the question then put the query

Comment: The clue is in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sec_to_time(489.73*60);
```

output

```
08:09:43.80
```

Comment: i tried that and didn't worked, but i have seen my mistake i put sec_to_time(min) * 60

the only problem now lacking of 1 second

Comment: 08:09:43.997999 here is the result in my query

Comment: happy to help :)